# Floating Action Button bad rendering

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I'm getting some troubles with a Floating Action Button in my application. In Android Studio emulator it looks good, both in the "design" view of the xml file that in the emulator of the app, but in a real device, when I run the app it doesn't have a circular shape, but it's oval.
Furthermore, this error happens only on some execution... Yesterday the FAB was circular also on my device, but not today (I haven't modified the xml part and on the Java side I don't handle its aspect)...

This is my .xml file where I define the button:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coor"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_weight="0.88">

   <!-- Other elements-->

   <!-- Parent element-->   

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etEntrate"
            android:textSize="@dimen/subtitles"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/data"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/data"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etSpese"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

  <!--FAB-->
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/plus"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etEntrate"
            android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etEntrate"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etEntrate"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etEntrate"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etEntrate" />

   <!--other elements-->
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here there are two pictures of how I see the FAB on my device and how it looks on the emulator:

FAB on my device:

[image: FAB on my devic]

FAB on the design view of Android Studio

[image: FAB on the design view of Android Studio]

Has anyone some idea about this? Thank you!

Comment: First use  `android:src` to set FAB drawable then can you tell me why you are align it with both left and right of `etEntrate` element? Draw a draft of what you want to archive. Ciao!

Comment: Which version of design support library are you using ?

Comment: try changing the margin top.

Comment: Grazie @fillobotto! I read it several times but I never noticed this stupid error... Now it is circular, of course! If I change 'android:srcCompat' into 'android:src' I get a "No resource identifier found for attribute src in package...", so I'm using 'srcCompat'. If you answer the question I can accept it and close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course FAB width and height are set to `wrap_content` but you are trying to align to both left and right, this is why it stretches.
Just remove either one of them.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Gravity in Horizontal Orientation, you have to use layout_width=0dp & in case of vertical Orientation, layout_height=0dp for every child inside layout.

**or**

just remove floating action button from Relative Layout because you are already using Coordinate Layout.

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coor"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_weight="0.88">

   <!-- Other elements-->

   <!-- Parent element-->   

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etEntrate"
            android:textSize="@dimen/subtitles"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/data"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/data"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etSpese"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

  <!--FAB-->
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/plus"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etEntrate"
            android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etEntrate"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etEntrate"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etEntrate"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etEntrate" />

   <!--other elements-->
    </RelativeLayout>
```